# Enki deployment to Heroku - problems with assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I cloned this https://github.com/xaviershay/enki and did the following modifications:

My Gemfile now looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
  gem 'trinidad'
  gem 'jruby-openssl'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9', :require => 'redcloth'
gem 'ruby-openid', :require => 'openid'
gem 'rack-openid', :require => 'rack/openid'
gem 'aaronh-chronic', :require => 'chronic' # Fixes for 1.9.2
gem 'coderay'
gem 'lesstile'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 2.5.2'
gem 'open_id_authentication'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails',    :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-websteps', :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0'
  gem 'webrat'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

And I also modified the database.yml file to look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: myblog_development
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: myblog_test
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

I am able to check the site in my local, but when trying to deploy to Heroku I get the following:

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

I tried doing what they suggest in that last site, but still getting the same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

In your application.rb file, add this line:

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false